# How to align text in a line with a specific character in the line above?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I would like LaTeX to produce the formatting in the first image but it produces the formatting found in the second image. I have tried `\begin{frame}{text}\end{frame}` as well as `\flushleft` and `\raggedright`. These help but they don't produce exactly what I want.

Thank you in Advance for any help/guidance

[image: What I'd Like]

[image: What Latex Automatically does]

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you literally typed `(a) Find the ...`.
If you want to *enumerate* different things, you should simply use the `enumerate` environment.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
\item \lipsum[1]

I did this at xyz

\item \lipsum[2]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The enumerate environment does the indentation as you want (in the standard article class).

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to do. Thank you very much. I'm new to LaTeX and stack exchange.

Comment: @user112202 I would then recommend to you to search for some tutorials and introductions to LaTeX, e.g. on [wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Introduction).

Comment: There is also itemize, description, \hangindent and \leftskip plus \llap.